# objective c help - calling methods?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, xcode, ios4

Hey, 
I am new to programming I wanted to know why is it always [self method];? I mean why is it that way could someone explain me why is it self and what is going on in the background? sorry if it is a stupid question

thanks, 
TC

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, what `self` refers to is the object that you're currently in the context of. `[self somemethod]` means that you're invoking a method named `somemethod` in the class that `self` was initialized as.

For example, if you were to do something like this:

```
Foo *f = [[Foo alloc]init];
[f someMethod];
```

You'd be invoking `someMethod` on the `Foo` instance.

But if you're working inside of the class `Foo`, self serves as an explicit reference to the current object. In this case, you'd simply use `[self someMethod]` to invoke `someMethod`.

```
-(id) init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        [self someMethod];
    }
    ...
}

-(void) someMethod { }
```

Does that help?

Comment: okay so baciscally if ur working say suppose in class a and u want to call a method from class b u would go [b nameofmethod]; and if u want to call method from the very same class (ie class a) you would go [self nameofmethod]; if that is the way it is then thanks a ton

Comment: That's the idea, yes. Updated my answer with an example of how you'd use self.

Answer (score 0):

Because `[self method];` calls the `-method` method in the class from which it is called.

Answer (score 0):

1. [self method] calls the method of the calling class. For example, in the header file of your class,

   @interface YourClass : NSObject {

   }

   - (void) myMethod;

then, you can call the 'myMethod' in YourClass by using [self myMethod]. Does it make sense?

1. During calling [self method], there is no any background working. [self method] is almost same the calling function in C. When you use [self method], 'method' in your class is just called right away.

Answer (score 0):

If you want kill John in ObjC:

```
[john sendBullet]
```

if you do sendBullet `to myself` (shortly self), it's a suicide

```
[self sendBullet]
```

got the difference? :)